# Is it not possible to save a file in S3 bucket instead of choose a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to save a data file into S3 through AWS Glue Job.

I am trying using spark dataframe as

```
df.coalesce(4).write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("s3://my_own_bucket/")
```

When I test it, the code return an error

```
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not create a Path from an empty string'
```

If I try with to place a file inside a folder like

```
df.coalesce(4).write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("s3://my_own_bucket/folder1")
```

the file is placed in the folder "**folder1**"

Anyone knows the reason of why I cannot place a folder in bucket level?

PS:
I also tryed using dynamic frame and works. I wanna know why using "normal" spark does not work.

```
final_sink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = frame1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://my_own_bucket"}, format = "parquet")
```

Comment: Try removing the last trailing slash in the first snippet.

Comment: `folder1` is the object key in your case. The failing code is missing the object key, as it only includes the S3 bucket name (`my_own_bucket`), hence the error.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answers.
@luk2302 I tried that way but the error was the same

Comment: @Dunedan so why works well if I try with dynamic frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is "no". you can't write a DF to the root of any file system, it's just that nobody has ever tried to use file:// or hdfs:// as a destination. root dirs are "special" -you can't delete them, the path relative to root is "", etc. nobody has ever sat down to add the feature

see [SPARK-34298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34298)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please remove "/" from path

```
df.coalesce(4).write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("s3://my_own_bucket")
```

Comment: Hi @Dhruv, thanks for your response. I already tried without the last "/" but the error was the same.  IllegalArgumentException: 'Can not create a Path from an empty string'